# Struts tag in Javascript call

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I have a JSP page where I want to say something like:

```
<... onclick="alert('<bean:message key="msg.oops" />')" ... />
```

This does not work. The page is not rendered.  It works fine if I have just:

```
<... onclick="f('Oops!')" ... />
```

How should this be done?

Comment: "The page is not rendered" -- Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bean:define to copy the message, then use a JSP expression.

```
<bean:define id="oops"><bean:message key="msg.oops"></bean:define>
<... onclick="alert('<%= oops %>') ... />
```